# Cassandra Python driver WARNING on table metadata

Tags: python, cassandra

I've been using the 2.1.4 version Python driver for Cassandra to retrieve some data. I ran some simple `SELECT * from table` statements listed below:

```
import cassandra.cluster as cc

# connecting to localhost
db = cc.Cluster(); 
session = db.connect(keyspace)

# statment is a simple select
session.execute(boundStmt)
```

I can successfully get my results back, however, I see a bunch of warnings before the results are returned, listed below.

Have no idea what they are, **is there a way I can fix this?** My Cassandra version is 2.1.2.

```
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.IndexInfo
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.batchlog
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.compaction_history
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.compactions_in_progress
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.hints
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.local
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.paxos
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.peer_events
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.peers
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.range_xfers
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.schema_columnfamilies
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.schema_columns
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.schema_keyspaces
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.schema_triggers
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.schema_usertypes
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for system.sstable_activity
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the source, they link to a ticket over here [(CASSANDRA-8487)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8487):

```
def _build_table_metadata(self, keyspace_metadata, row, col_rows, trigger_rows):
    cfname = row["columnfamily_name"]
    cf_col_rows = col_rows.get(cfname, [])

    if not cf_col_rows:  # CASSANDRA-8487
        log.warning("Building table metadata with no column meta for %s.%s",
                    keyspace_metadata.name, cfname)
```

What you are experiencing seems like an (intermittent) bug (some nodes having consistent metadata for all columns in some cases) which was closed as 'non reproducible' for 2.1.3.

Perhaps you could try to update to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Interesting. Will try an upgrade and see what happens. Thanks!